# Is there a way to find if there is a specific sum in an array without using a nested loop? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

so this code works but i was wondering how would this be done if i do not want to use a nested loop? would appreciate if we could stick to the basics tho! hehe :>

edit: the list to be entered is already sorted in ascending order, if that helps!

```
import java.util.*;

class Tuple {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of distinct elements in sorted array: ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter " +size+ " elements: ");
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
      arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Enter key: ");
    int key = sc.nextInt();
    if (checkTuple(arr, key)) {
      System.out.println("Exist");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Not exist");
    }
  }
  
  // method , returns true if there exists at least 1 pair of integers 
  //whose sum equals key, or false otherwise
  public static boolean checkTuple(int[] arr, int key) {
    int[] remainder = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i]+arr[j]==key) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;  
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do it using a `Set`.

Comment: You don't even need to store the numbers if you simply know what numbers are present (as a set). If both `n` and `key - n` are in the set, then you're all... set.

Comment: oH i didnt think of that since i havent learnt sets :( but i took a quick crash course and i managed to implement it! yay thanks! @AndyTurner

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using following method. It has only one loop.
The `arr` input parameter must be sorted in ascending order.
The algorithm relies on the fact that array is sorted.
Initially we summarize first and last elements of the array. If our desired sum is lower than sum of current pair, in that case we need to decrease the right index. Otherwise, if desired sum is higher than sum of current pair, in that case we have to increase left index.

So, in worst case scenario we will traverse through the whole array only once. So, the complexity will be O(n)

```
public static boolean checkTuple(int[] arr, int key) {
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = arr.length - 1;

    while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
        int currentSum = arr[leftIndex] + arr[rightIndex];
        if (currentSum == key) {
            return true;
        }

        if (currentSum > key) {
            rightIndex--;
        } 
        if (currentSum < key) {
            leftIndex++;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: the method will return `false` as expected.  As i understood the question, `true` should be returned only if there exists pair that gives you `key`  in sum. Not just one element of the array.

Comment: complexity is `O(n)` if the array is sorted...

Comment: @josejuan yes, the array must be sorted. But author wrote that we can expect it to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed to use a number twice, you need to build a Map, recording the number of occurences of each number in the array:

```
Map<Integer, Long> counts =
    IntStream.of(arr).boxed().collect(groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting());
```

Then, loop through the keys of the map:

```
for (int key : counts.keySet()) {
  // You need key + otherKey == target.
  int otherKey = target - key;

  long otherCount = counts.getOrDefault(otherKey, 0L);

  // otherKey wasn't in the array.
  if (otherCount == 0) continue;

  // key and otherKey aren't equal, so you don't need two (or more) occurrences.
  if (key != otherKey) return true;

  // key and otherKey are equal, so you need two (or more) occurrences.
  if (otherCount >= 2) {
    return true;
  }
}

// Didn't find a match.
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point something out that you are not using the remainder array in your code.
and you can use one for loop bye replacing the method with something like this

```java
  public static boolean checkTuple(int[] arr, int key) {
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i]+arr[i]==key) {
                    return true;
                }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

just take away the for loop and change `j` to `i`

Comment: That won't work if the two numbers that sum to the key are at different positions in the array. That only works if there's a number in the array that is half of the key.

Comment: "that is half of the key" and you're allowed to use the same number twice.

Comment: i tried this initially but sadly it doesnt work :( also,, yess i just realised that i forgot to remove the remainder list from a previous attempt HAHA

Answer (score 0):

No need to store the array. Just check to see if there's a matching pair while reading the elements. Of course, you need to ask for the key in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Tuple {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of distinct elements: ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter key: ");
    int key = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter " + size + " elements: ");
    Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      int value = sc.nextInt();
      if (arr.contains(key - value)) {
        System.out.println("Exist");
        return;
      }
      set.add(value);
    }
    System.out.println("Not exist");
  }
}
```

(I realize this is almost certainly a homework problem and the purpose is not to find out whether a pair exists, but to write the `checkTuple` method, but if the purpose *were* merely to find out if a pair exists, this approach is both time and space efficient.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in `O(n)`

```
static boolean sum2(int[] xs, int s) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int x : xs)
        if (set.contains(s - x))    return true;
        else                        set.add(x);
    return false;
}
```

for example

```
int[] xs = new int[]{5, 5, 12, -7, 21};

System.out.println("====  all pairs should match ===");
for (int a = 0; a < xs.length; a++)
    for (int b = a + 1; b < xs.length; b++)
        System.out.println(sum2(xs, xs[a] + xs[b]));

System.out.println("==== false cases ===");
System.out.println(sum2(xs, 12 + 12));
System.out.println(sum2(xs, -5));
```

with output

```
====  all pairs should match ===
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
==== false cases ===
false
false
```